# How to use git-filter-branch to test commits

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have a suspicion that some of the last 150 commits in my repository are broken -- that is, the code won't compile if I checkout one of those commits.  I think I can use git-filter-branch to test this, but I'm confused by the parameters.  I came up with this:

git filter-branch -f --commit-filter 'git commit-tree "$@"; cd ../..; make defconfig; make' HEAD^..

But I get this output instead:

```
$ git filter-branch -f --commit-filter 'git commit-tree "$@"; cd ../..; make defconfig; make' HEAD^..
Rewrite 4c3b2950f53717ba22280a76c211c9eab3135348 (1/1)arch/arm64/kernel/setup.c: In function 'arm64_spcr_setup':
arch/arm64/kernel/setup.c:615:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'acpi_setup_spcr' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   acpi_setup_spcr();
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [arch/arm64/kernel/setup.o] Error 1
make: *** [arch/arm64/kernel] Error 2
could not write rewritten commit
```

This makes no sense to me.   The compilation error does not match the last two commits in my repo, and what does "could not write rewritten commit" mean?  I'm obviously doing something completely wrong, but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 2):

This is not what `git filter-branch` is designed to do.

What filter-branch does, described as simply as possible, is this:

- For some set of commits (based on arguments), make *copies* of those commits after checking out each commit, applying the filters, and checking in the result.
- For some set of branch names (and optionally, tag names as well), make new branch (and optionally tag) names pointing to the new copied-after-filtering commits.

You can (as you've tried to do) compile each commit while it's checked-out during the "filtering" stage, but because filter-branch is not designed for this, and is instead optimized to *avoid* actually checking out commits whenever possible,<sup>1</sup> it's a lot harder than you might think.

In short, filter-branch is the [wrong tool](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0517722/quotes).

(Usually the correct tool here is [`git bisect`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html), which skips back and forth between commits looking for the point at which some bug was introduced, rather than plowing linearly through *every* commit to see which ones are good.  It's not entirely clear to me what your intent is, though, so perhaps it's not the right tool for your case.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The check-out and re-check-in parts of the filtering process tend to be the slowest, so whenever filter-branch can avoid doing a "real" out-and-in, it does.  That's why there's an `--index-filter`, and why `--commit-filter` doesn't actually extract any trees.  (The `--tree-filter` forces a full checkout, but it will likely behave badly for your case, unless your compilation process is read-only.)

Answer (score 1):

This seems...***dirty***.

All you want to do is check out the commits, one at a time, compile them, and run tests against them, right?

What you can do instead is check out those commits, starting from 1 up to however many you want to go back, run the tests, and report the result of the test to a file.

This will get you *started*:

```
for i in $(seq 1 150);
do
    git checkout HEAD~$i;
    make defconfig && make;
    git checkout master;
done
```

There is probably a more elegant way to go about this, but the principle is thus:

- You're going through each commit, one at a time in a detached HEAD state.
- You're running whatever steps you need to in order to build the branch *at that moment in time*.
- You run the tests (and record them; this I leave as an exercise for the reader).
- You then restore the state of the branch, so that it points back to its original HEAD.

A slightly more elegant approach would be to only move the branch back once you're done:

```
COUNT=0
while [ $COUNT -lt 150 ];
do
    git checkout HEAD~1;
    make defconfig && make;
    let $COUNT=$COUNT + 1;
done
git checkout master;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a shot.  I'd still like to know how to use git-filter-branch to do what I want.  I'm having a hard time understanding how this feature works.

Comment: @RichardFallon:  filter-branch isn't meant for what you're trying to do.  Normally, you would use it to rewrite huge swaths of history, not run a diagnostic on some number of commits.